# Unable to use spree_advanced_inventory in spree 3.0

Tags: spree, inventory-management

While adding spree_advanced_inventory gem to an existing spree application I am getting the following error.

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in
>   'method_missing': undefined method 'attr_accessible' for

Then I added `protected-attributes` gem to my gem file, ***bundle install*** worked well, but when I tried ***bundle exec rails g spree_advanced_inventory:install*** giving me result as

> "SPREE doesn't work with protected_attributes gem installed"

Answer (score 0):

spree_advanced_inventory extension is for spree 1.3.2 which was most likely be tested for rails <= 3.x which uses `attr_accessible` whereas you are using spree 3.0 which uses rails >= 4.x which now supports permitted attributes.

Because of some compatibility issues spree do not support `protected_attributes` gem hence the error.